# if else java algorithm and psuedocode

Tags: java, if-statement, pseudocode, flowchart

1. We would like to assess a service charge for cashing a check. Th service charge depends on the amount of the check. If the check amount is less than 10$, we will charge 1$. If the amount is greater than 10$ but less than 100$, we will charge 10% of the amount. If the amount is greater than 100$, but less than 1,000$, we will charge 5$ plus 5% of the amount. If the value is over 1,000$, we will charge 40$ plus 1% of the amount. Use a multibranch/nested if-else statement to compute for the service charge.

tried writing source code but failed.

Comment: *tried writing source code but failed* Maybe try again?

Comment: edit your question, share your failed code, we'll suggest imrovements to your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will look like this. I put the amount randomly.

```
    int amount = 500;
    double pay = 0;
    if(amount > 1000){
        pay = 40+(amount*0.01);
    } else if(amount > 100 && amount < 1000){
        pay = 5+(amount*0.05);
    } else if(amount > 10 && amount < 100){
       pay = amount*0.1;
    } else if(amount < 10){
        pay = 1;
    }
    System.out.println(pay+"$")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public double getCharge(int check_amount) {

        if (check_amount < 10) { 
            return 1;
        } else if (check_amount < 100) {
            return 0.1 * check_amount;
        } else if (check_amount < 1000) {
            return 5 + 0.05 * check_amount;
        } else if (check_amount > 1000) {
            return 40 + 0.01 * check_amount;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

If we start with the lowest condition, we can neglect to have two conditions in the if statement.

In the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(getCharge(9)) //when value is less than 10
   System.out.println(getCharge(90)) //when value is less than 100
   System.out.println(getCharge(900)) //when value is less than 1000
   System.out.println(getCharge(5000)) //when value is greater than 1000
}
```

Output:

```
1
9
50
90
```

Answer (score -1):

The question asks for nested if statements, so this code may fair better:

```
public double getCharge(int check_amount) {

        if (check_amount < 1000){
            if (check_amount < 100){
                if (check_amount <10){
                    return 1;
                }else {
                    return 0.1*check_amount;
                }
            } else {
                return 5 + 0.05*check_amount;
            }
        } else {
            return 40 + 0.01*check_amount;
        }
    }
```

This has the same function as the previous code i posted but as nested if-else statements as per request.